# Query text() over dynamically added img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I realize it's probably an already answered question, but I wanted to ask, if there is something new on the market, that can easily solve my issue.

I'm loading images to specified coordinates using javascript.

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "<img src=\"source.gif\" id=\"someid\">";
span.style.position = "absolute";
span.style.left = coodinatesLeft[i] + "px";
span.style.top = coodinatesTop[i] + "px";
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Later on, when the mouse goes over the images I want to use the simple mouseenter function in jquery

```
$("mydivid").mouseenter(function(){  $(this).text("something"); });
```

to write a text there, where the image is. And I don't get any text, I suppose, because the image is more foreground then the text. Other times I've used it, and it worked, but then I just had a div, and no actual image source on it.

Is there a way to keep the structure and append the text over the image?

PS: I read about the z-index, but not sure if it is exactly what I need, since I don't have a pre-defined css class for the images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the "mydivid" element: a container for the all images or a text container moving from image to image or something else? Since you append spans with images directly to the body the purpose of "mydivid" is not clear.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Mydidiv is just the div's id's. It would be replaced in the actual code with '#div' + i  inside a for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `event delegation` for dynamically added elements.

```
$('<span />')
    .html('<img src="source.gif" class="myImages">')
    .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': coodinatesLeft[i] + 'px',
        'top': coodinatesTop[i] + 'px'
    })
    .appendTo('body');


$('.myImages').hover(function() {
    $(this).append('<span id="myText">MY TEXT HERE</span>');
}, function() {
    $('#myText').remove();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#myText {
    height: same as .myImages;
    width: same as .myImages;
    opacity: .5;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Perphaps I should have specified more. I don't want to cover the image completely. That's why I was looking for something else then z-index. I need the text to be actually within the div, as it should have been, if there was no image there. And the mouseenter function works in my code as long as no css classes handling is needed exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "<img src=\"source.gif\" id=\"someid\" class=\"image-class\">";
span.style.position = "absolute";
span.style.left = coodinatesLeft[i] + "px";
span.style.top = coodinatesTop[i] + "px";

var imgText = document.createElement("span");
imgText.className = "overlay-text";
span.appendChild(imgText);

document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Add the following css:

```
.image-class {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.overlay-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Please checkout this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/duLL2wrj/

```
$("#mydivid").mouseenter(function(){  $(this).children('.overlay-text').text("something"); });

$("#mydivid").mouseleave(function(){  $(this).children('.overlay-text').text(""); });
```

Comment: Elegant solution, I could see it applied in my case, but it's not dynamically changable. It creates a Text at the point of appending the image, so it's not really a mouseover kind of thing. Anyway nice! :P

Comment: I have updated for it to work with mouse over. Please check out the jsfiddle to see how it works.